# How can we obtain the state value of a variable from previous block number using web3

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, web3.py

I have a private chain and I am running own archiving node. The node connected with `--fast cache=1024` option.

For example I have a set function on my smart contract.

```
contract smartContract {
    uint  value;
    function set(uint input) returns (bool success) {
         value = input;
    }
    function getValue() public view
     returns (uint)
    {
        return value;
    } 

}
```

This function is called at block number 100 and 200.

```
smartContract.set(10) //deployed at block number 100
smartContract.set(20) //deployed at block number 200
```

At this point. if our blockchain is sync, as we know, when we call `smartContract.get()` it returns 20.

[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/42065/4575) mentions that smart contact can only see the current state.

> A contract can only see the current state when it executes, not
>   previous states. This restriction allows validating nodes to work only
>   with the current state, rather than needing to store and be able to
>   access all the previous states.

[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1589/4575) we can get previous blocks data. Since we can obtain previous block data, we could obtain the previous states.

**[Q]** Could web3 retrieve state of a value from previous block numbers instead of returning the its latest state value?

If we provide the block number such as 100, `smartContract.get() at 100`; somehow can web3 return `value`'s value at block number 100 instead at `latest`?

Comment: [web3.js 0.2 can](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)

Comment: How? I couldn't find the specific example on the link you share. How about `web3.py` ? @Henk

Comment: An alternative might be to fire an event when the state variable is changed.

Comment: That's possible but I want to take event out of the table, since it has been already been stored in the memory, and I don't want consume additional gas for the event.  @Jesse Busman

Comment: @Alper When you make a [query](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) you can pass an extra parameter with the block number, default is 'latest' but you can pass 'pending' or an explicit block number/hash. The issue is that non-archive clients will only have the more recent 256 states, querying a block beyond that range will return an error.

Comment: Which means that I cannot obtain previous state of variables through web3 and instead my only option to use using events? @Ismael

Comment: @Alper You are not guaranteed to retrieve old states, unless you run your own archiving node or you explicitely save all changes in your contract storage.

Comment: If I am running my own archived node, how could I achieve it? @Ismael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Q] Could web3 retrieve state of a value from previous block numbers instead of returning the its latest state value?

Yes, in web3.py v4.0+.

When making a contract call, you can specify a block number (or hash). These examples are from the [web3.py docs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.call):

```
# You can call your contract method at a block number:
>>> token_contract.functions.myBalance().call(block_identifier=10)

# or a number of blocks back from pending,
# in this case, the block just before the latest block:
>>> token_contract.functions.myBalance().call(block_identifier=-2)

# or a block hash:
>>> token_contract.functions.myBalance().call(block_identifier='0x4ff4a38b278ab49f7739d3a4ed4e12714386a9fdf72192f2e8f7da7822f10b4d')
>>> token_contract.functions.myBalance().call(block_identifier=b'O\xf4\xa3\x8b\'\x8a\xb4\x9fw9\xd3\xa4\xedN\x12qC\x86\xa9\xfd\xf7!\x92\xf2\xe8\xf7\xdax"\xf1\x0bM')

# Latest is the default, so this is redundant:
>>> token_contract.functions.myBalance().call(block_identifier='latest')

# You can check the state after your pending transactions (if supported by your node):
>>> token_contract.functions.myBalance().call(block_identifier='pending')
```